# boost spirit x3 error handler with expectations

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-x3

I want to create a parser using `boost::spirit::x3` for line based files, e.g. every line has the same structure and can be repeated. Further I want some detailed error description in case there is an error. Finally it should be possible that the file ends with a new line character.

Now I encountered some weird behavior in case I use `x3::expect` on the first element of the line. The error handler prints an error, but the overall parsing does not fail. Why is this happening? And how it can be fixed? If I do not expect the first element of the line, I do not get a detailed error description.

Here is an example to reproduce this problem:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/utility/annotate_on_success.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/utility/error_reporting.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/define_struct.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct error_handler
{
    template<typename Iterator, typename Exception, typename Context>
    x3::error_handler_result on_error(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last,
                                      Exception const& x,
                                      Context const& context)
    {
        auto& error_handler = x3::get<x3::error_handler_tag>(context).get();
        std::string message = "Error! Expecting: " + x.which() + " here:";
        error_handler(x.where(), message);
        return x3::error_handler_result::fail;
    }
};

namespace boost::spirit::x3 {
    template<>
    struct get_info<int_type>
    {
        std::string operator()(int_type const&) const
        { return "integral number"; }
    };

    template<>
    struct get_info<char_type>
    {
        std::string operator()(char_type const&) const
        { return "character"; }
    };
}  // namespace boost::spirit::x3

struct Line_tag : error_handler
{
};
struct File_tag : error_handler
{
};

BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT((), Data, (char, c)(int, x))
BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT((), DataContainer, (std::vector<Data>, data))

template<bool ExpectFirstElementOfLine>
DataContainer parse(std::string_view input)
{
    auto iter = input.cbegin();
    auto const end = input.cend();

    const auto charParser = []() {
        if constexpr (ExpectFirstElementOfLine)
            return x3::expect[x3::char_("a-zA-Z")];
        else
            return x3::char_("a-zA-Z");
    }();

    const auto line = x3::rule<Line_tag, Data>{"line"} = charParser > x3::int_;
    const auto file = x3::rule<File_tag, DataContainer>{"file"} = (line % x3::eol) >> -x3::eol >> x3::eoi;

    x3::error_handler<decltype(iter)> error_handler(iter, end, std::cout);
    DataContainer container;
    if (parse(iter, end, x3::with<x3::error_handler_tag>(std::ref(error_handler))[file], container))
    {
        if (iter != end)
            throw std::runtime_error("Remaining unparsed");
    }
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Parse failed");

    return container;
}

template<bool ExpectFirstElementOfLine>
void testParse(std::string_view input)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "=========================" << std::endl;
        const auto container = parse<ExpectFirstElementOfLine>(input);
        std::cout << "Parsed [OK]: " << container.data.size() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::string_view input1 = "x1\nx456";
    const std::string_view input2 = "x1\nx456\n";
    const std::string_view input3 = "x1\n456\n";
    // OK
    testParse<true>(input1);
    testParse<false>(input1);

    // parse succeeds but error handler prints message if expectation on first element of line is used
    testParse<true>(input2);
    testParse<false>(input2);

    // parsing fails but detailed error description only works if first element of line was expected
    testParse<true>(input3);
    testParse<false>(input3);
}
```

which yields:

```
=========================
Parsed [OK]: 2
=========================
Parsed [OK]: 2
=========================
In line 3:
Error! Expecting: char-set here:

^_
Parsed [OK]: 2
=========================
Parsed [OK]: 2
=========================
In line 2:
Error! Expecting: char-set here:
456
^_
EXCEPTION: Parse failed
=========================
EXCEPTION: Parse failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why there is an expectation failure for `testParse<true>("x1\nx456\n");`?

   The `(line % x3::eol)` will run three times for that input:

   1. Try `line` -- ok (consume `x1`), try `x3::eol` -- ok (consume `\n`), repeat
   2. Try `line` -- ok (consume `x456`), try `x3::eol` -- ok (consume `\n`), repeat
   3. Try `line`, it tries `x3::expect[x3::char_("a-zA-Z")]`, but fails -- here comes expectation failure
2. The error handler prints an error, but the overall parsing does not fail. Why is this happening?

   When an expectation parser fails -- it throw an `expectation_failure` exception. However, when you set up an error handler for a rule -- the rule will catch the exception for you, and call your error handler. The error handler signals the rule with result of error handling by returning an appropriate value of `error_handler_result` enum type.

   Your error handler returns `error_handler_result::fail` -- this signals the rule to just fail the parsing, effectively turning `expect[x]` into `x`. In other word, your error handler is just a semantic action on failure (instead of on success for usual semantic actions).

   The list parser `line % x3::eol` is just `line >> *(x3::eol >> line)`. Because your error handler turns any expectation failure to a regular failure, it should be obvious that after the first successful parsed `line` any fail will not fail the whole parsing.
3. And how it can be fixed?

   You did not mention what you want exactly. If you just want that an `expectation_failure` exception propagate -- return a `error_handler_result::rethrow` from your error handler.

Comment: I would like that parsing "x1\n456\n" and "x1\n456" gives the same results. I tried to fix the expectation failure for the empty line by changing the line rule to `const auto line = x3::rule<Line_tag, Data>{"line"} = (-x3::eol >> x3::eoi) | (charParser > x3::int_);` but then there are 3 items in the container.

Comment: "I would like that parsing "x1\n456\n" and "x1\n456" gives the same results." - which one exactly (of two possible)? " I tried to fix ... but then there are 3 items in the container." - Spirit does not perform roll back on backtracking (this is pointed out many times in documentation, bug tracker, mail list, SO, etc).